# Advice for installing SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have a Laptop which is partitioned as:

c:/ Windows 8
E:/ Windows 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 R2 and SharePoint
F:/ Windows Server 2012

Now on my f:/ i would like to install sharepoint 2013, but have about 130 gb left.
Is it enough for development?

Should I go for a VM for SQL Server and another VM for a AD server or just the SQL server.

My laptop is a I7 with 16 gb ram

Best regards and TIA

Comment: 130GB should be more than plenty. SharePoint will take 40-50GB meaning you still have 80-90GB free space left for activities! Of course if you also want Search server installed I'd recommend virtual boxes.

Comment: which edition - Foundation or Std/Ent Server?

Comment: It´s Sharepoint Enteprise Server 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to go for a Virtual Machine to have your SharePoint Server installed. No need to go for separate VMs for SQL and AD. One is enough for both.

Why I am saying to go for Virtual Machine is "SharePoint Server" works fine with Windows Sever 2012 than Windows 8 when going for Farm installation.

The the steps would be

1. Crate a Virtual Box from Oracle (It is free)
2. Install Windows 2012 with all updates
3. Set up the AD
4. Install SQL 2012
5. Install SharePoint Server
6. Install Visual Studio 2012
7. SharePoint Designer 2013

This is what I had followed. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So you recommend this: On my drive f:/ where Windows Server 2012 is preinstalled - just go for the whole music. AD, SQL 2012, Sharepoint 2013, VS2012 and SD2013. A single Server install, no N-tier installatition? Will it perform good

Comment: Having SQL in a separate machine will certainly make difference. Otherwise I don't think much performance improvements. Do you agree?

Comment: Hmm - I don't know.
My Laptop has only one HD and it's partitioned as mentioned above. To put SQL Server on another drive ( C or E) would be the same drive anyway. Or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think your machine should be enough if you turn off search.

I will also recommend you to consider hyper-v. It should be faster than VirtualBox in most cases, and should also work fine since you are running Win8.

In your case, you can  run a VM with SQL and AD on E: and a VM for Sharepoint on F:

But if all is the same HD, and just different partition, you might aswell just run everything on C: And use Hyper-V. Using Hyper-V will also make it easier for you to move it to another drive / machine if needed later on.

Comment: Ok my drive f: boot up with windows server 2012. No need for making a VM for the OS. Or is it?